# Destroy method test doesn't fail, although JavaScript alert window is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a Rails App, testing with RSpec and Capybara

I have following test:

```
context 'destroy user' do
    scenario "should be successful" do
      user = User.create(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', email: 'john.doe@example.com')
      visit users_path

      click_link 'Destroy'
      # expect { click_link 'Destroy' }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)

      expect(page).to have_content 'User was successfully destroyed'
    end
  end
```

I have following link in the browser:

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

I run the test, and the test passes. It shouldn't pass, since I have the alert window before calling the action.

I installed

```
brew cask install chromedriver
```

because I wanted to test JS, but unfortunately test is not failing.

rails_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rails'

# Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome ### not working

# require "support/factory_bot"
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  # Filter lines from Rails gems in backtraces.
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

Once the test fails, I would improve the test with:

```
accept_confirm do
    click_link 'Destroy'
end
```

I think my problem is, I don't know where to put the line:

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome ### not working

Where do I create the file for the config of Capybara? In the official documentation, they say in the lib/capybara.rb

I tried there, and I get the error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/user_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

Bundler::GemRequireError:
  There was an error while trying to load the gem 'capybara'.
  Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Capybara
  Backtrace for gem load error is:
  /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:74:in `block in load_missing_constant'
  /Users/albert/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what "official documentation" told you to configure Capybara in `lib/capybara.rb` but it should be configured in a file that is only loaded during test running.  Generally that's the same place as RSpec is configured (when using RSpec) so rails_helper.rb or spec_helpers.rb depending on you're exact setup.  You also should require capybara/rspec in your spec_helper.rb as documented in the Capybara docs - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your Capybara config (`default_driver`/`javascript_driver`), and you also don't have `js` metadata on your test which would imply you're possibly using the rack_test driver to run your tests.  The `rack_test` driver doesn't support JS and therefore would completely ignore the JS confirm. If you want to test JS behaviors you need to make sure you're using a driver that actually supports JS - see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers and https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#using-capybara-with-rspec